# How to get CollisionPolygon2D from sprite Region

Tags: sprite, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to get the `polygon` data (so I can add it to my custom node) from a `CollisionPolygon2D` sibling created from a `Sprite` via Code:

[image]

but I'm running into multiple problems:

1. How do I `Create CollisionPolygon2D Sibling` via code?
2. When I select Region `Enabled` as true and then create, it gives a weird offset like this:

[image]

3. Having to create a `CollisionPolygon2D` sibling first, getting its polygon and then deleting it is power consuming, is there a way I can directly get the polygon?

To Avoid an **XY** problem allow me to explain what I'm trying to achieve:

My `Sprite` texture changes in-game, so after it changes I need the `CollisionPolygon2D` to automatically change accordingly & I'm looking for the least power consuming solution

**Edit:**

when I meant sprite I meant a [irregular transparent image](https://pics.clipartpng.com/midle/Green_Realistic_Tree_PNG_Clip_Art-1097.png), for example [this](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/27553) does what I need but it doesn't work via [code](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/27553#issuecomment-483716447), so is there some other way to achieve this?

I even tried this script I found on an old forum:

```
extends CollisionPolygon2D
tool

export (bool) var from_sprite= false setget set_from_sprite

func set_from_sprite(new_val):
    var bitmap = BitMap.new()
    
    var children=self.get_children();
    
    for child in children:
        if(child.get_class()=="Sprite"):
            if(child.texture==null):
                continue
            bitmap.create_from_image_alpha(child.texture.get_data())
            var rect = Rect2(child.position.x, child.position.y, child.texture.get_width(), child.texture.get_height())

            var polygons = bitmap.opaque_to_polygons(rect,0.5);
            print(polygons)
            self.polygon=polygons[0]
            self.position -= Vector2((child.texture.get_width() / 2), (child.texture.get_height() / 2)) * child.scale.x
            self.scale = child.scale

            break;
    property_list_changed_notify();
```

but it isn't as precise as `Create CollisionPolygon2D sibling`

Comment: Isn't a Sprite always rectangular? I'd say use `get_rect` to create a `RectangleShape2D` which you could put in a `CollisionShape2D` if you need to… But you want a `CollisionPolygon2D`, so what am I missing?

Comment: @Theraot I only took a rectangular sprite for the example, I need to get the polygons from a sprite so I can use it in my custom node. The sprite (png) can be of any shape

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Sprite` would always be a rectangle, which you can get with `get_rect`, and the best way to get a polygon from a rectangle is to make it yourself.

Something like this:

```
static func rect_corners(rect:Rect2) -> PoolVector2Array:
    # Return the positions of the corners of a Rect2.
    # Assuming the size is positive, the points should be:
    # 0: bottom-right, 1: bottom-left, 2: top-left, 3: top-right.

    var start := rect.position
    var end := rect.end
    return PoolVector2Array(
        [
            end,
            Vector2(start.x, end.y),
            start,
            Vector2(end.x, start.y),
        ]
    )
```

---

I don't know what shape you actually want to do. But have a look a the [Geometry](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_geometry.html) class. It might be useful, in particular if you can create your polygon by doing boolean operations of simpler polygons (see `clip_polygons_2d`, `exclude_polygons_2d`, `intersect_polygons_2d`, and `merge_polygons_2d`). *See also the `convex_hull_2d` method.*

Be aware that you can apply `Transform2D` to a polygon (`PoolVector2Array`). More precisely `xform` and `xform_inv` can take and work on `PoolVector2Array`.

---

By the way, `Bitmap` has an [`opaque_to_polygons`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_bitmap.html#class-bitmap-method-opaque-to-polygons) method that might also be useful, depending on the situation. It should give you a polygon based on the alpha of the pixels of the `Bitmap` on the given `Rect2` (`epsilon` is the resolution, it uses [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares), so a smaller `epsilon` will be more precise but also result in more points)… Which might be useful for complex shapes, or might be overkill, or might not be convenient at all.

Comment: I've edited the question to further explain

Comment: @cakelover I see. As you found `opaque_to_polygons` is the closest to that, but it uses a different algorithm. And the one Godot uses is not exposed to scripts… Which would mean we would have to recreate/port it.

Comment: Yes exactly and I don't know enough to do so

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `port` it?

Comment: @cakelover I meant translate and or adapt it. - By the way, I had a look at the code, and I was having a hard time understanding it. Now, I have looked for algorithms, and found [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/potrace.pdf). I think something like that could work: walk around the edge of the image (perhaps in a reduced resolution version of the image), it could be simplified further afterwards if necessary (The [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer–Douglas–Peucker_algorithm) would do). I may try that in GDScript another day.

Comment: well both these seem out of my scope at the moment, but if you ever to write the code in gdscript let me know, also is there anyway to get a polygon outline? not necessarily only for collisionPolygon2D? maybe convert sprite to Polygon2D?